# Change the Date to Commercial Date MyS

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime

I need change the Date of my database considering the Commercial Date used in the enterprise that I work.

Here, a commercial month is between `YYYY-(M-1)-26` and `YYYY-M-25`.
Where M-1: last month.

For example, today the commercial date is `2017-08-26` and `2017-09-25`.

But the problem is in the range 26 to 31 (or 30 or 28, last day of the month), because, in this range, the commercial date should be `YYYY-M-26` and `YYYY-(M+1)-25` and when turn of the month it will be `YYYY-(M-1)-26` and `YYYY-M-25` again.

I create a query for this, but the issue in the range above I could not fix.

```
select 
concat(
(       -- se mes tem 31 dias
        if(month(current_date()) in (1,3,5,7,8,10,12),
            -- então, diff(now() - data_i) <= 5? Se sim, incrementa +1 no mês, se não deixa -1
            if(datediff(current_date(), date_format(concat(year(current_date()),'-',month(current_date()),'-',26),'%Y-%m-%d')) <= 5, date_format(concat(year(current_date()),'-',month(current_date())-0,'-',26),'%d/%m/%Y'),date_format(concat(year(current_date()),'-',month(current_date())-1,'-',26),'%d/%m/%Y')),
        -- se mes n tem 30 dias, ele tem 30 dias?
        if(month(current_date()) in (4,6,9,11),
            -- então, diff(now() - data_i) <= 4? Se sim, incrementa +1 no mês, se não deixa -1
            if(datediff(current_date(), date_format(concat(year(current_date()),'-',month(current_date()),'-',26),'%Y-%m-%d')) <= 4, date_format(concat(year(current_date()),'-',month(current_date())-0,'-',26),'%d/%m/%Y'),date_format(concat(year(current_date()),'-',month(current_date())-1,'-',26),'%d/%m/%Y')),
        -- mes 29
        if(month(current_date()) in (2),
            -- então, diff(now() - data_i) <= 4? Se sim, incrementa +1 no mês, se não deixa -1
            if(datediff(current_date(), date_format(concat(year(current_date()),'-',month(current_date()),'-',26),'%Y-%m-%d')) <= 3, date_format(concat(year(current_date()),'-',month(current_date())-0,'-',26),'%d/%m/%Y'),date_format(concat(year(current_date()),'-',month(current_date())-1,'-',26),'%d/%m/%Y')),
        999)))
    )
,' a ',
(       -- se mes tem 31 dias
        if(month(current_date()) in (1,3,5,7,8,10,12),
            -- então, diff(now() - data_i) <= 5? Se sim, incrementa +1 no mês, se não deixa -1
            if(datediff(current_date(), date_format(concat(year(current_date()),'-',month(current_date()),'-',26),'%Y-%m-%d')) <= 5, date_format(concat(year(current_date()),'-',month(current_date())+1,'-',25),'%d/%m/%Y'),date_format(concat(year(current_date()),'-',month(current_date())+0,'-',25),'%d/%m/%Y')),
        -- se mes n tem 31 dias, ele tem 30 dias?
        if(month(current_date()) in (4,6,9,11),
            -- então, diff(now() - data_i) <= 4? Se sim, incrementa +1 no mês, se não deixa -1
            if(datediff(current_date(), date_format(concat(year(current_date()),'-',month(current_date()),'-',26),'%Y-%m-%d')) <= 4, date_format(concat(year(current_date()),'-',month(current_date())+1,'-',25),'%d/%m/%Y'),date_format(concat(year(current_date()),'-',month(current_date())+0,'-',25),'%d/%m/%Y')),
        if(month(current_date()) in (2),
            -- então, diff(now() - data_i) <= 4? Se sim, incrementa +1 no mês, se não deixa -1
            if(datediff(current_date(), date_format(concat(year(current_date()),'-',month(current_date()),'-',26),'%Y-%m-%d')) <= 3, date_format(concat(year(current_date()),'-',month(current_date())+1,'-',25),'%d/%m/%Y'),date_format(concat(year(current_date()),'-',month(current_date())+0,'-',25),'%d/%m/%Y')),
        999)))
    )
) as 'DataMesComercial'
;
```

Comment: I encourage you to populate a business calendar table following your business rules. It would be clear and you improve performance on joins and where conditions. Do you need help with that?

Comment: @Horaciux Thank you very much. Yeah, but I'm building a data warehouse here and my dimension Date has more than 30 thousand registers. And I have a trouble with leap years, Feb and Jul/Aug that broke a logical rule to create this table. If I would create this table by hand, ok, issue solved, but I'm not gonna do this by hand, then... how to do this with a script? What the logic to apply here? And If I know the logic I know the query.

Comment: what date sets your period? initial date or end date? refacing it. what column should have all real dates with no leaps? start period or end period?

Comment: A brother, Ivan, solved my deficient logic. Something like this: `If current date is between YYYY-MM-01 and YYYY-MM-26 then my date will be YYYY-(MM-1)-26 and YYYY-MM-25 else it will be YYYY-MM-26 and YYYY-(MM+1)-25`. Thank you @Horaciux for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I'd simplify the problem by trying to first figure out how many days we are into the "commercial month" by using the 25th as a starting point.  From there, you can determine, as you describe, whether to go from M to M+1, or M-1 to M.

For example: (SQL fiddle at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2228d7/41)

```
SET @date = DATE('2016-04-21');
SET @commercial_day = DAY(@date)-25;
SET @commercial_month_start_offset = IF(@commercial_day<0, -1, 0);
SET @commercial_month_start = DATE_ADD(@date, INTERVAL @commercial_month_start_offset MONTH);
SET @commercial_month_end = DATE_ADD(@commercial_month_start, INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
SET @commercial_date_start = DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(MAKEDATE(YEAR(@commercial_month_start), 1), INTERVAL (MONTH(@commercial_month_start))-1 MONTH), INTERVAL (25)-1 DAY );
SET @commercial_date_end = DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(MAKEDATE(YEAR(@commercial_month_end), 1), INTERVAL (MONTH(@commercial_month_end))-1 MONTH), INTERVAL (26)-1 DAY );
SELECT @date, @commercial_date_start,@commercial_date_end;
```

I tried this with a few different dates, and if I understood the logic correctly, believe this will work for you.  You could probably convert this to a MySQL function returning the start date or end date, or a string as your example does above.

I also created this as a function with a test routine in SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/634312/1

This should allow you to validate the logic for 2017.